# DataFrame to_sql None caused Oracle error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert Daraframe data into Oracle table, and got error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB". It's caused by one column in database which is Number type and Nullable, while my data in Daraframe for that column is None.

My original data is from sqlite3. I googled many place, people say sqlalchemy might have problem handling date time type for Oracle. I tried to drop columns one by one, and it actually, turns out date time column is fine but one column in Oracle database is Number and Nullable, and my Daraframe for that column is None. If I drop this column then everything is fine.

```py
try:
  dest_server_cnn.begin_nested()
  cdf.to_sql(name=tab['table'].lower(), con=dest_server_cnn, if_exists='append', index=False)
  pbar.update(total)
except:
  e_type, e_message, e_traceback = sys.exc_info()
  failed_count += total
```

The Exception

```
<class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError'> Error: (cx_Oracle.DatabaseError) ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got CLOB
[SQL: INSERT INTO alloc_test ....]
```

I cannot put a value for this column since there's business logic tied to the value. So how do I handle this None column?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the reason and solution. It's because Pandas treat all columns, string, and int as object when it read empty column.

[image: all columns become object type except datetime]

I have to convert the column to integer, then it will work.

```
to_sql(... dtype={"int column with null": Integer()})
```

Comment: [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13049) Exact same issue reported on GitHub